# How to deploy a WinJS 3 app to Azure as a website?

Tags: azure, winjs, azure-web-app-service

How to deploy [a WinJS 3 application](https://github.com/banguero/winjs-cordova-stocks-sample) to Azure? Should the application be included in an ASP.NET MVC to publish to the Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app is like the sample WinJS app you've linked to, you do not need to wrap it any additional web frameworks. Simply deploy your static `/www` HTML/CSS/JS files to the root `site\webroot` web directory.

If you deploy the entire Cordova app, including the 'www' folder, you should be able to apply a virtual directory rewrite to point `/` to `site\webroot\www` in the web app's portal settings.